# block specific url requests with no referring urls

Tags: .htaccess, woocommerce

I have a big problem with my woocommerce shop filtering. there are many requests on my attribute links that increase cpu and ram usage.
the requestes urls are like these:

```
example.com/product-category/skincare/repair/?filter*
example.com/product-brand/skincode/?filter*
```

```
sample of attacks link: https://s6.uupload.ir/files/attack2_z574.png
```

i think its an attack from somewhere trying to down my website. these requests has no referring url with different user agents. so i want to block these requests but i dont want to block real requests. so i need to have a htacess code like this.
i dont know how to add another condition (no referring urls) with this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-category/.* - [F]
```

Comment: Well, just add a second condition using the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` variable. See the documentation for details. But this looks pretty straight forward.